# Portably include GLib headers in autoconf/automake

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, pkg-config

I need to include the [GLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) headers for a project that is built with an autoconf-based system for portability.

How can I safely import the GLib headers in a portable manner? I know about [pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), but that is not entirely portable (since some systems don't have it and I would prefer to only rely on autoconf for configuration).

Comment: Which systems don't have pkg-config?

Comment: By "don't have" I mean don't have great support for it by default (ie Windows)

Comment: Either way, I would prefer to do it with just autotools if possible. If necessary, I can resort to pkg-config.

Comment: By default no system has it. In windows you can use a native one http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html or the cygwin one.

Comment: If you want to go with autotools, you'll have to check a few well-known folders for glib header files and libraries and then set variables for what you find.

Comment: Great question, I am tripping over the same problem right now.

Comment: If you have glib on windows you get a version of pkg-config with it, basically just assume you have it if you're building with autotools. It'd be kind of stupid to have mingw and glib without getting pkg-config... that'd just be shooting yourself in the foot (same goes for cygwin) if someone building your code is that obtuse, just ignore them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GLib 2.22 `INSTALL` file states that `pkg-config` is a requirement for installing this library.  I am not being GLib (pun intended!); statement of this requirement is one of the first things on the top of the `INSTALL` file.

From the text surrounding it is unclear whether `pkg-config` is needed to compile GLib itself, however it is clear that GLib 2.22 authors do not intend for any users to compile against GLib without having pkg-config.  In particular, GLib's `make install` will install `.pc` files appropriately.

For platform portability, instruct the user to set `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` appropriately.

Answer (score 12):

By using the [`PKG_CHECK_MODULES`](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html) macro, Autoconf-generated `configure` scripts can retrieve pkg-config data automatically. As an example, adding this line to your `configure.ac` file:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [glib-2.0 >= 2.24.1])
```

will cause the resulting `configure` script to ensure that the installed version of glib-2.0 is greater than or equal to version 2.24.1 as well as append to variables `DEPS_CFLAGS` and `DEPS_LIBS` the output of `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` and `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`, respectively. You then use the `$(DEPS_CFLAGS)` and `$(DEPS_LIBS)` variables in the `_CFLAGS` and `_LDADD` primaries:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello

hello_CFLAGS = $(DEPS_CFLAGS)
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
hello_LDADD = $(DEPS_LIBS)
```

Comment: Should be `hello_LDADD` not `hello_LIBS` in the `Makefile.am`.

Comment: @ecerulm: I think that `hello_LDADD` is for when your project uses [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).

Comment: No, that would be `hello_LIBADD`. `hello_LIBS` doesn'exist. `*_LIBS` is NOT mentioned in the [automake doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Program-and-Library-Variables) . I tried  `hello_LIBS` didn't have any effect on the `gcc` command that gets executed. It's completely ignored whereas `hello_LDADD` has the desired effect of adding the `$(DEPS_LIBS)` at the end of the `gcc` command line.

Comment: @ecerulm: Ah!  You are right.  I will correct my answer.