# Adding GLib to an existing application with gnu toolchain (configure, Makefile, etc.)

Tags: makefile, configure, glib, autoconf, automake

I've added code to an existing large application and need to make GLib a requirement, as my code relies on it.  For development, I just manually edited the Makefile to add

```
-lglib-2.0
```

To the LIBS= variable and

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include $<
```

to the line starting with ${CC}.

However, I am at a loss for how to make this permanent/portable in the app -- i.e. when someone executes ./configure in the future, the resulting Makefile should also include the above (as appropriate, since these depend on pkg-config output, I've learned).   The codebase I updated includes the following files from the gnu tool chain:

```
Makefile.in
Makefile.manual
config.h.in
configure
configure.in
```

I only have a handful of CS degrees and a few years of development experience, so the GNU toolchain remains utterly impenetrable to me. :-/ From googling around, I'm under the impression there should also [be a configure.ac file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732822/portably-include-glib-headers-in-autoconf-automake) or something where I should add a macro for requiring glib, but no such file is included in the package and I'm at the point of learned helplessness with the whole automake/autoconf/configure/makefile business.   Thanks in advance for any advice or pointers!

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not edit any generated files manually. This includes the final Makefile used to build the application.
2. In `configure.ac`, every dependency is listed, thus checking for GLib should go in there. From this file, your final `configure` shell script is generated.
3. GLib provides a [pkgconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) description so you almost always want to use this to get the correct compile and link flags.
4. Combining pkgconfig and Autotools is just a matter of calling the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro. The [Autotools Mythbuster](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html) is an excellent source that describes how to do it.
5. In the end it boils down to adding these lines to your `configure.ac`:

   ```
   PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG
   PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GLIB], [glib-2.0])
   ```

   and these lines to your `Makefile.am`:

   ```
   foo_CXXFLAGS = $(GLIB_CFLAGS)
   foo_LIBS = $(GLIB_LIBS)
   ```

Comment: You know you can use `foo_CXXFLAGS = $(GLIB_CFLAGS)`, right? automake automatically adds variable assignments of the form `GLIB_CFLAGS = @GLIB_CFLAGS@` for any `AC_SUBST`'d variable, unless it's been suppressed by `AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE`.

Comment: Thanks, I previously found this macro (see my link in the question) but my problem is that the package does not distribute the configure.ac file (nor Makefile.am). So, I don't have it. :-/ It only distributes the files I listed in my question above.  Can I modify one of them?

Comment: @JJC: Are you sure you have all the sources and not just a dist tarball?

Comment: I've successfully made a 1000 LOC C patch to the code, so I'm pretty sure I have the source. :-9

Comment: There is a difference between the sources that _generate_ the `configure` script and the distributed sources that contain said script. Anyway ... concerning that tool: It still uses the older `configure.in` convention instead of `configure.ac` and a hand-written `Makefile.in`.